# Var overflow in JS and mongo

Tags: javascript, mongodb, var

I am working in javascript and mongo. I have to store and work with very large integers e.g. `pow(10,30)` maybe even more. I am concerned about overflowing, does this happen in mongo or in javascript if I use var ? I know that JS function `toPrecision()` works up to 20 digits, but what happens if I have more ? And what about mongo, when does the stored number overflow ?

Comment: Maybe this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-max-int-whats-the-highest-integer-value-a-number-can-go-t

Comment: You'll need to use a math library and store numbers as strings or as separate components of a larger number. I don't understand your question about use of `var` though.